# Tile services ON TOP of default CartoDB Basemaps?

Tags: carto, tiles, basemap

I'd like to place a tile service of a georeferenced map from DavidRumsey.com in a CartoDB map, but I don't want it to be the 'basemap'. I want it to lay on TOP of the basemap, which would be any of the default choices.

Any way to do this within the GUI? Obviously it can be done with Leaflet, etc... but I'm writing guidance for a non technical class to use CartoDB for a History of San Francisco project, so I'd like to keep them in the GUI.

Comment: Leaflet is not that hard :D They might benefit from seeing how it all fits together.

Comment: Cartodb editor doesn't have raster support yet. If and when cartodb supports raster formats, you could upload the georeferenced raster and create the overlay.

Comment: CartoDB has raster support but the filtering we use is not meant for images but for data raster

Answer (score 1):

For the moment CartoDB editor does not support to add third party tiled layers on top of CartoDB layers.

In case we'd add support we would publish in our blog http://blog.cartodb.com/